# UseEffect does not trigger when using context as dependency and context is updated

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I am using a custom hook for a component's state. I use useEffect to update the state with a dependency on context. When I update the context, my useEffect does not trigger. I can see the context values being updated through a console log and the react dev tools.

Here is the custom hook

```
export const useFilteredTrans = (
  type: string,
  transactions: Transaction[] | undefined
): Transaction[] | null => {
  const [filteredTrans, setFilteredTrans] = useState<Transaction[] | null>(null)
  useEffect(() => {
    if (transactions && transactions.length > 0) {
      const filtered = transactions.filter(
        (transaction) => transaction.type === type
      )
      setFilteredTrans(filtered)
    }
  }, [transactions])
  return filteredTrans
```

And here is the component that uses context and the custom hook:

```
export const Expenses = () => {
  const {
    currentAccount: { transactions },
  } = useContext(AccountContext)
  const expenses = useFilteredTrans('e', transactions)

  return (
    <div>
      <Module>
        <div className='mb-4 flex justify-between'>
          <h1>Expenses</h1>
          <ShowAddModalButton modalType='e' entityType='e' />
        </div>
        {expenses
          ? expenses.map((expenseItem) => {
              const { id, date, expense, credit, amount } = expenseItem
              return (
                <div className='grid grid-cols-5 gap-3' key={id}>
                  <p className='col-span-2'>{fmtDateString(date)}</p>
                  <p>{expense?.name}</p>
                  <p className='text-right'>{credit ? '+ $' : '- $'} </p>
                  <p className='text-right'>{amount}</p>
                </div>
              )
            })
          : null}
      </Module>
    </div>
  )
}
```

The context is being updated through a reducer that takes the new transaction from the server and adds it to the current account that is being rendered.

```
    case 'ADD_EXPENSE': {
      const account = state.currentAccount
      account.transactions?.unshift(action.payload)
      return { ...state, currentAccount: account, isLoading: false }
    }
```

When I add a new expense, the transactions are updated in the context, but the custom hook with state isn't updated. Am I missing a piece of code or my understanding of the useEffect hook completely off?

Comment: I realized the loading state I used to render my components was inefficient, and fixed it and used the context directly without the custom hook. However, I would still like some clarification on what I might be doing wrong in the code above to further my understanding on the topic.

Comment: How/where are you updating the context? Please include that in your question.

Comment: @ivanatias I've updated the question. A function from the context sends the input for a new expense to my API server and receives the entity back and dispatches to a reducer to update the context state. Please let me know if there's something else i need to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand the full logic, but it seems that the reducer might be mutating the existing state before `return`. As an attempt perhaps try:

```
case 'ADD_EXPENSE': {
  const { transactions } = state.currentAccount;
  const newtransactions = transactions
    ? [action.payload, ...transactions]
    : [action.payload];
  return {
    ...state,
    currentAccount: { ...state.currentAccount, transactions: newtransactions },
    isLoading: false,
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't really "safe" to modify the original state directly, since `unshift`, just like `push` method, modify the original array in-place:

```
const account = state.currentAccount
account.transactions?.unshift(action.payload)
return { ...state, currentAccount: account, isLoading: false }
```

Try make a copy of the state at the beginning:

```
const copiedState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state));
const account = copiedState.currentAccount;
account.transactions?.unshift(action.payload);
return copiedState;
```